# CLI errors during Headless CMS Sanity integration with Nextjs

Tags: require, sanity, modulenotfounderror, esbuild, headless-cms

First, I have created a new template using `npx create-next-app@latest`. After that I have used the command suggested by sanity website to integrate sanity studio in my nextjs project.
That command is `npm create sanity@latest -- --template clean --create-project "Sanity Project" --dataset production`.

After that instead of asking me Login details, I am facing the error shown in following code.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'esbuild'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\67a0730928194b24\node_modules\esbuild-register\dist\node.js
- C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\67a0730928194b24\node_modules\@sanity\cli\lib\_chunks\getCliConfig-3f875ac6.js
- C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\67a0730928194b24\node_modules\@sanity\cli\lib\_chunks\cli-2c8129a8.js
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Bilal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\67a0730928194b24\\node_modules\\esbuild-register\\dist\\node.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Bilal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\67a0730928194b24\\node_modules\\@sanity\\cli\\lib\\_chunks\\getCliConfig-3f8
75ac6.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Bilal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\67a0730928194b24\\node_modules\\@sanity\\cli\\lib\\_chunks\\cli-2c8129a8.js'
,
    'C:\\Users\\Bilal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\67a0730928194b24\\node_modules\\@sanity\\cli\\lib\\run.js',                     'C:\\Users\\Bilal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\67a0730928194b24\\node_modules\\@sanity\\cli\\bin\\sanity'
  ]
}
```

I am expecting someone to tell me some solution after which it asks me my sanity login details.